# Can I create Multiple arrays dynamically based on a key value with jolt?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jolt

I have a following JSON :

```json
{
  "timestamp": 1665923527,
  "place": "us",
  "event": "custom",
  "Users": [
    {
      "email": "test1@test.com",
      "key1": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "email": "test2@test.com",
      "key1": "Admin"
    }
  ]
}
```

which I want to modify it to multiple array based on the users key dynamically. In the above example I have 2 arrays inside user. So I want the output to be:

```json
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1665923527,
    "place": "us",
    "event": "custom",
    "email": "test1@test.com",
    "key1": "Admin"
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1665923527,
    "place": "us",
    "event": "custom",
    "email": "test2@test.com",
    "key1": "Admin"
  }
]
```

Is it possible with Jolt?

I did search in all the documents i found, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk through the attributes of the innermost array(`Users`) by using a **shift** transformation spec while copying the values of the others grabbed from after going two levels up the tree such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,timestamp)": "[&1].timestamp", // go 2 levels up the tree to grab the value of timestamp by using "@(2,timestamp)", [&1] stands for going 1 level up to reach the level of "Users" array to combine all values at that level 
          "@(2,place)": "[&1].place",
          "@(2,event)": "[&1].event",
          "*": "[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

**Edit** : alternatively you can prefer the below one to make it dynamic :

```json
[
  {
    // separate the attributes into two groups "x" and "y"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Users": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@": "x.&2.&"
          }
        }
      },
      "*": "y.&"
    }
  },
  {
    // combine each attributes under common index values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "x": {
        "*": {
          "@(2,y)": "&2.&"
        },
        "@": "&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // dive deep into indexes
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "x": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Barbaros. But is it possible for timestamp, place and event keys also to be dynamic? for example if there are more than 10-12 keys then it should just take whatever the keys there and create a new array based on user email id